# Word Frequency count in a very inefficient way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time, word-cloud

This is my code for calculate word frequency

```
  word_arr= ["I", "received", "this", "in", "email", "and", "found", "it", "a", "good", "read", "to", "share......", "Yes,", "Dr", "M.", "Bakri", "Musa", "seems", "to", "know", "what", "is", "happening", "in", "Malaysia.", "Some", "of", "you", "may", "know.", "He", "is", "a", "Malay",  "extra horny", "horny nor", "nor their", "their babes", "babes are", "are extra", "extra SEXY..", "SEXY.. .", ". .", ". .It's", ".It's because", "because their", "their CONDOMS", "CONDOMS are", "are Made", "Made In", "In China........;)", "China........;) &&"]

arr_stop_kwd=["a","and"] 

 frequencies = Hash.new(0)
   word_arr.each { |word|
      if !arr_stop_kwd.include?(word.downcase) && !word.match('&&')
        frequencies["#{word.downcase}"] += 1
      end
   }
```

when i have 100k data it will take 9.03 seconds,that,s to much time can i calculate any another way

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Facets gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/facets)

You can do something like this using the [frequency method](http://rubyworks.github.com/rubyfaux/?doc=http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/docs/facets-2.9.3/core.json#api-module-Enumerable/api-method-Enumerable-h-frequency)

```
require 'facets'
frequencies = (word_arr-arr_stop_kwd).frequency
```

Note that stop word can be subtracted from the `word_arr`. Refer to [Array Documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-2D).

Comment: Sir I am using ruby 1.8.7 when i require 'facets' i found an error stack level too deep how can i solve this

Comment: you need to install the gem. Try running  `gem install facets` or add 'facets' to your `.gemfile` if you are using bundler

Comment: Strange, facets documentation says - "The 2.x versions of Facets are designed to work with Ruby 1.8.6 and up. Facets is fully compatible with Ruby 1.9".